# Find latest record for the same customer

Tags: sql-server

I am tracking a movement of customers subscribing & un-subscribing to a newsletter. So basically any one subscribes, his details will be filled in a SQL table along with the subscription date. If the same user un-subscribes, a new record will be inserted along with the un-subscription date. If the same customer subscribes again, a third record will be inserted to the table.

I have one column in my table to show the latest status of the customer whether he is subscribed or not. The tricky part is I want only the third record to have the word "Yes". What I am trying to do is a loop to go through all my records & mark "Yes" if this is the latest record for the customer

Thank You

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful in conveying what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, you should show your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an update.  Something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from subscriptions s
     )
update s
    set is_last_subscription = (case when seqnum = 1 and subscription_date is not null then 'YES' end);
```

However, I would guess that you have a customer/subscriber table and it would be better to either calculate the value when you need it or update that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
update T
set Flag = 'Yes'
where not exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.CustomerId = T.CustomerId
        and t2.Timestamp > T.Timestamp
);
```

This is the classic set-based approach. It will work on platforms that don't have window functions and it avoids the broken `from` clause on updates.

Comment: @lmo This is one of the most common questions under SQL. I'm indifferent to upvotes for these stock answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try some thing similar

```
UPDATE [DBO].[SUBSCRIBE] SET [STATUS] = 0 WHERE [CUSTOMERNAME] = 'A'
UPDATE [DBO].[SUBSCRIBE]  SET [STATUS] = 1 WHERE  [ID] IN 
(SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM [DBO].[SUBSCRIBE] ORDER BY [SUBSCRIPTIONDATE] DESC )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update t set status = 
  case when z.LastSub >= z.LastUnSUb 
       then 'Yes' else 'No' end
From table t join
  (Select ClientID,
      Max(SubscriptionDate) LastSub,
      Max(UnsubscriptionDate) LasUnSub
   From table  
   Group by ClientID) z
 On z.ClientId = t.ClientId
```